# Скажите пожалуйста, ставится ли запятая в этом случае?

Tags: запятые

Интересует момент, где в предпоследнем предложении после слова *или* я поставил запятую. Должна ли она тут стоять? Заранее спасибо.

«Через какое-то время люди начали слышать от его сына нехорошие слова. Например, они начали слышать от него, что он говорит, что правды нет.  Или слышали от него, что он говорит на некоторых лжецов, что они праведники. Или, что отличия между праведниками и заблудшими - это небольшой вопрос. Вот такого рода слова».

Answer (score 3):

*Или слышали от него, что он говорит на некоторых лжецов, что они праведники.Или, что отличия между праведниками и заблудшими - это небольшой вопрос.*

Это парцеллированная конструкция. Уберём парцелляцию: *Или слышали от него, что он говорит на некоторых лжецов, что они праведники, или что отличия между праведниками и заблудшими - это небольшой вопрос.*

Видно, что ИЛИ соединяет два однородных придаточных: Или слышали от него, что он говорит на некоторых лжецов ... или что отличия между праведниками и заблудшими - это небольшой вопрос. Запятой после союза нет.

Answer (score 0):

1.1. В данном случае лучше не взирать на парцелляцию и вообще её не касаться.

1.2. Итак, запятая ставится. Дело в том, что в "Или, что отличия между праведниками и заблудшими - это небольшой вопрос" слово "что" - это "то, что", где опустили местоимение "то". То есть можно сказать "Или [слышали от него] **ТО**, что отличия между праведниками и заблудшими - это небольшой вопрос". Вообще, всегда "что" можно заменить на "то, что", так как это одно и то же, а когда "то" опускают, то получаются такие странные случаи. Но смысл-то не изменяется при этом, поэтому пунктуация сохраняется такой же.